# VBA debug Issue on Mac / "Step Into" and "Run to Cursor" execute the whole sub

Tags: excel, vba, macos, vbe

I am working through a course right now and have a very simple macro:

```
Sub Test()

Debug.Print 200 / 200

Range("a1") = 1
Range("a2") = 2

Range("a3") = 3 / "t1"

End Sub
```

I can't use "Step Into" or "Run to Cursor" to run this or any other macro step by step.

When I try to use "Step Into" to execute the code line by line, the whole sub executes immediately. When I use "Run to Cursor" the whole sub executes regardless of where my cursor is. Additionally, I tried to see if I could get into debug mode by adding a line that should obviously raise some sort of error (Range("a3") = 3 / "t1"), but it seems like that line just gets skipped when I run the sub. I don't think the problem has anything to do with this sub specifically, because I had the same kind of problems when I had to debug a more complicated sub that I built for a project. The debugger doesn't stop mid execution and highlight in yellow when there is an error, it seems like the line just gets skipped, which make debugging very difficult. Is there something obvious I might be missing? Maybe a setting that needs to be changed or something like that?